# Testing Frameworks for C

Tags: c, unit-testing, tdd, rspec

After doing some work with Ruby, Rails, and RSpec last summer and I learned to [TATFT](http://smartic.us/2008/8/15/tatft-i-feel-a-revolution-coming-on). Now I can't write code without writing tests first.

I'm taking a programming course in C next year, and I would like to learn to write C test-driven. Is it a good idea (or even possible) to do TDD with C? If so, are there any good testing frameworks compatible with C?

Comment: see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242926/comparison-of-c-unit-test-frameworks#242942

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it a good idea (or even possible) to do TDD with C?

Yes, it obviously is a good idea, as with other languages. However, due to the procedural nature of the language, it comes with its some more difficulties.

- Static functions quickly get in the way. This can be solved by including the source file under test, or defining a STATIC macro that only means static when compiling the code for production - not unit test

  ```
  #if defined(UNIT_TEST)
  #define STATIC
  #else
  #define STATIC static
  #endif
  ```
- There is no isolation: there is only one global context. With an OO language you can just instantiate one object (or a cluster of collaborating objects) to test it (them), you can also use mock objects.
  With C, you can, however, override functions just by re-defining them in your unit tests. This works fine on Unix-like systems where the linker invokes the first function he is finding - I'm not sure on Windows.

---

> If so, are there any good testing
>   frameworks compatible with C?

You can start small with [minunit](http://www.jera.com/techinfo/jtns/jtn002.html). The learning curve is flat as it only is four macros long.

EDIT: There are two **lists of UT frameworks for the C language**, that were mentioned in other answers and I didn't repeat : [one on Wikepedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C) and [another one on xprogramming.com](http://www.xprogramming.com/software.htm).

Answer (score 2):

We use "check" from http://check.sourceforge.net/, it provides basic functionality for testsuites and tests (similiar to junit), but is fairly lightweight.   On feature I like is that it handles if your test dumps code and considers that a failure.

Also note "check" is a "C" based framework rather than a "C++" one.

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered [CSpec](http://wiki.github.com/arnaudbrejeon/cspec), which does [BDD](http://behaviour-driven.org/) in C. Doesn't look very mature, but it reminds me of RSpec.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of unit testing harnesses for C.  Wikipedia has a much better list than I could assemble [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C).

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually using a C++ compiler, but using it in 'C' mode by compiling .c files, then, also, any of the C++ unit test frameworks will work OK.

Take a look at the original list of xUnit frameworks at http://www.xprogramming.com/software.htm

Answer (score 1):

This similar question also has a lot of answers ["Unit Testing C Code"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65820/unit-testing-c-code)

I used [RCUNIT](http://rcunit.sourceforge.net/), it is mature and has everything I need. I have also used ipl canata which is great but is very expensive so that is probability not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can do unit testing in C (I do). The framework I use (for the Windows platform) is [CunitWin32](http://code.google.com/p/cunitwin32/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of unit test frameworks for c:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C

enjoy it!

Answer (score -1):

So a proper C programmer will tell you that because C is statically typed it catches all bugs you might have and therefore you don't need a unit test framework.

They are full of shit, but that's the argument for statically type languages like C.

I think you should probably take the approach that Adobe did with Photoshop. Write a series of core libraries in C, and then all the glue and real logic of the application should be in a higher level language. Photoshop is mostly written in Lua, but many languages work for this.

Comment: Sorry, java is statically typed, and I've never heard the argument that you shouldn't unit test your java code.  I agree that anyone saying that is full of it, but I just haven't heard that argument with regard to static/dynamic typing and I think it confuses the issue.

Comment: I don't know which C programmers you work with who claim that, but they ain't proper C programmers by my standards.  It is trivial to have bugs in C that are unrelated to type (as in every language) and unit testing helps no end in finding and eradicating them.