# boost.test vs. CppUnit

Tags: c++, boost, cppunit, boost-test

I've been using CppUnit for quite a while now (and am happy with it). As we are using more and more parts of the boost library I had a short look on boost.test and I'm wondering now if I should switch to boost.test in a new project or not.

Can anyone here tell me about the differences between the two frameworks and the benefits (if there are any) of using boost.test?

Comment: You'll probably find the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242926/comparison-of-c-unit-test-frameworks useful.

Comment: @Alex: thanks for your post, there are some really helpful links in it

Comment: Good link, AAlex, +1.  @chrmue, to clarify - should the comparision that are you looking for assume a Boost user or not? Are you asking "if I use Boost to develop, then is there an advantage to using Boost text?" or are you just looking for a straightforward comparision?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and go straight to [Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/), which makes CppUnit and `boost::unit_test` look clunky and repetitive.

For example, say you have a simple fixture:

```
class MyFixture : public ::testing::Test
{
  protected:
  int foo;

  virtual void SetUp() { foo = 0; }
};
```

To add a test to your fixture, write it!

```
TEST_F(MyFixture, FooStartsAtZero) {
  EXPECT_EQ(0, foo);
}
```

That's all you need. Notice the lack of explicit testsuite declarations or a separate agenda that repeats all your tests' names.

Compile it as in

```
$ g++ -o utest utest.cpp -lgtest -lgtest_main
```

and run your test to get

```
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from MyFixture
[ RUN      ] MyFixture.FooStartsAtZero
[       OK ] MyFixture.FooStartsAtZero (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from MyFixture (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

(Run it yourself to see the nice green text for passing tests!)

This is only the beginning. Take a look at the [Google Test primer](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer) and the [advanced guide](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide) to see what else is possible.

Comment: +1 I was asking myself the same question, and this answer has prompted me to look at Google Test. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer! It doensn't really answer my question, but it pointed me to a unit test framework that I didn't know yet and that looks really promising.
What I like most at the first glance is the way how test cases are expressed: the shortest possible form!

Comment: @chrmue Thanks for considering it! You'll be thrilled with Google Test's power and expressiveness.

Answer (score 43):

How is this less clunky than Boost.Test alternative:

```
class MyFixture { MyFixture() { /* setup here */} };

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test, MyFixture )
{
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(0, foo);
}
```

Macros indeed a bit longer, but this is safer and is recommended practice in C++.

I am yet to see a single technical reason to prefer Google Test (and I know quite a few to prefer Boost.Test). The rest is just your preference.

Comment: I use Boost.Test a lot. Can you elaborate on "I know quite a few to prefer Boost.Test"?

Comment: Also curious as to why you prefer Boost.Test. What are the advantages over googletest?

Comment: What are those advantages?