# Boost Test Vs Google Test Framework

Tags: unit-testing, boost, automated-tests, googletest

I am new to Unit Testing world, basically I am c++ developer working on a large product for almost 3 years, and now I've decided to perform automated unit testing of my code. For this I do lot of research on the internet and came across many tools and frameworks and finally chose the following two: 
1) Boost Test Libraries
2) Google Test Framework for c++

Now I am confused as to which to choose from those. If someone uses any of the above then please share your experience.

Comment: The answer for old SO question ["boost.test vs. CppUnit"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100322/boost-test-vs-cppunit) compares Boost and Google Test.

Comment: http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/c-unit-testing-framework

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The below SO posts pretty much answer your questions

- [Comparison of c++ unit test frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242926/comparison-of-c-unit-test-frameworks)
- [Unit testing for C++ code - Tools and methodology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91384/unit-testing-for-c-code-tools-and-methodology)
- [C++ unit testing framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87794/c-unit-testing-framework)

Answer (score 13):

If you are already using `Boost libraries`, then stick to Boost Test Libs. It should take care of most of your logging requirements. Otherwise, Google-test is recommended. I've used it in a large project and found it easier to use. Most importantly compiler-error messages are easier to locate in GTEST; boost uses templates.

I have never written complicated tests using either of these two libraries. For simple tests, any of them would do fine. Although `google-test` will save you some compile time.

Boost-test with boost-log is really a good combination. Try it!

Comment: As of version 1.7, gtest also uses templates and the compiler-error messages are what can be expected - horrible.

Answer (score 8):

Suggest you take a look at [googlemock](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock), a superset of googletest.  Googlemock has all the testing capabilities of googletest plus the mocking capabilities of googlemock.

Comment: googlemock project has been absorbed into Google test.