# Practical way to test native C++ code in Windows?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have a couple of MFC applications. I don't want to unit-test UI but test all logics in the application for TDD. According to my research, I found two ways

1. Using C++/CLI and MSTest to build managed tests after restructuring your code into a static library
2. Using Google C++ Testing framework

I was almost sold to MSTest approach but changed my mind after reading [comments on a blog about it.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jsocha/archive/2010/11/19/writing-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-for-native-c.aspx) I want to spend my time to debug my application but not my tests for the application.

I am sure there are a lot of developers who are practicing TDD in C++. I would like to hear from them which way above is a good practice.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775253/boost-test-vs-google-test-framework) might be an interesting read

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparison of c++ unit test frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242926/comparison-of-c-unit-test-frameworks)

Comment: @Martin, I've already read the question/answers but it does not provide with what I wanted. What I'd like to know is not the list of test frameworks but the reasons to choose them or not.

Comment: @Paul - "I'd like to know ... not the list ... but the reasons to choose them or not" - and you'll find plenty of answers there and on links provided by these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google C++ testing framework is well worth looking into, I've used it on a number of projects.  You should be able to mock the UI classed you don't want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Boost.Test is also a very good testing framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into [Catch (C++ Adaptive Test Cases in Headers)](http://github.com/philsquared/Catch). Since it is header based it is very easy to get started with. In my experience it is also very easy to work with and I find that I write tests much faster in Catch than any other framework I have tried so far. The following  blog post by the author is a very good starting point: [Unit Testing in C++ and Objective-C just got easier](http://www.levelofindirection.com/journal/2010/12/28/unit-testing-in-c-and-objective-c-just-got-easier.html).