# Any ideas of what unit testing framework I should use for Visual Studio and Eclipse (Code Red)

Tags: c++, eclipse, unit-testing, visual-c++, testing

I am looking for a unit testing framework that work work on both IDE's as well as from command line. Ideally the framework would include code coverage as well. If anyone has any recommendations to point me in the right direction I'd be extremely grateful. Most of my applciations are MFC apps, if this is any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B - none of them will give you the features of junit unless you can write your tests in managed c++ and use nunit.

related question: [Comparison of c++ unit test frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242926/comparison-of-c-unit-test-frameworks)