# Automated unit testing in c++ mac OS

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have developed a project in c++ using eclipse and my OS is mac. I need to do automated unit testing and could anyone suggest a framework which is simple and easy to develop the test cases.

thanks

Comment: I've used CxxTest, it's pretty nice and very simple to setup as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) - What I really like is that it has [easy to understand documentation](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_Primer).

That's what I've tried and it works well.

You should really also read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242926/comparison-of-c-unit-test-frameworks).

Finally, there is this [comparison](http://gamesfromwithin.com/exploring-the-c-unit-testing-framework-jungle) between testing frameworks. It does not have Google Test though.

Rule of thumb: Keep it simple and don't speculate. Don't choose a framework because it has features you think you will need. Choose a framework that works for you, is under active development and is also used by a lot of others.

Answer (score 0):

Best c++ unittest system around is http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page