# provide unit-testing for c++ code

Tags: c++, unit-testing, verification

I need to provide unit tests for an application written in c++, this is a very big application and content many sources (.h, .cpp) , actually I don't know where to start? How to process? ...
So any help is more than  welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Have you done any research on unit testing yet?  Do you have any ideas how you might start?

Comment: Somehow a quote from a movie popped into my head: "Run, Forest, run!" Generally, code which isn't unit-tested isn't amenable to unit-testing. If it is my job to retrofit testing to existing code I start with the entities with least dependencies, working my way though to those with more dependencies, probably refactoring a fair amount of the code...

Comment: I just write my unit tests in C++ and put them all in a directory called 'tests'. The tests are run when I type "make test" at the command line. Write a test for each class/module of code, and make sure to cover all corner cases. Not all tests need be automated; I have a test in my game engine that requires visual inspection - but I still consider it a unit test. There's an example of a simple unit test on my website: http://robjinman.com/article.jsp?id=48. You may also wish to investigate unit testing frameworks - but I don't know much about those.

Comment: thanks for you reply, yes I done many researches on the web on creation of unit tests, and in all the examples i read, it's a small test case.
in my case i have many include many namespaces many funtions...

Comment: If you were looking for some silver bullet, magic wand, ancient treatise on the unit testing legacy code, you'll find it just right after the end of the rainbow, next to the holy grail and the foolproof plan to win the war on poverty. This is just hard work, in fact so hard, most businesses don't bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab a good test framework.

I have used google test a lot with my last company, and it was pretty good, though there are likely better around. 
Reading:
http://code.google.com/p/googletest/
[Comparison of c++ unit test frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242926/comparison-of-c-unit-test-frameworks)

Answer (score 4):

Did you upset someone? Given there are no unit tests, the chances of the code being written to be testable range from slim to absolutely none.

Without seeing the code and spending several weeks if not months with it no one can give you more than a general strategy.

There will be some functions you can write unit tests for. Those will be ones where the arguments are easy to generate, they do very few things, one thing would be nice, and they don't have side effects. Attack these first, get them out of the way.

There will be others which nearly fit the above. Now you'll be tempted to re-engineer them a bit so they do, don't do it until you have some sort of test. Write tests for the bits you can. Write integration tests where you can't.

So the basic idea is to get as many tests as you can before you start changing the code, so you can test it and then, to make the smallest change possible to make the code better and write the tests first!

There are a fair few patterns or strategies you can use (get a good book on re-factoring legacy code), start with the simple ones.

Prepare for dismay, hard work and rework, but the best piece of advice I can give is don't try to take short cuts, after all that's what the chuffer who left you with this did isn't it?

Comment: thanks tony, I'm not looking for short cuts, I know that i should work very hard to do this,
I'm just looking for the good way to do it.
"There will be some functions you can write unit tests for. Those will be ones where the arguments are easy to generate"
i already start doing this separation.

Comment: Wasn't really meaning you should work hard, do the people who tasked you with this understand how hard you will have to work? It's a lot of resources and a good deal of risk, make sure they know what they are getting into.