# (C++) Using Function test harness

Tags: c++, function, testing

About to begin using simple test harness to test my functions. I have a few questions.

Firstly, are they simply functions, that read other functions to test different outputs?

Secondly, are they typically executed at the beginning of the program?

If so, how do I test functions that edit data without them messing with the actual program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_harness
Test harness or Automated Test Framework is a collection of software and test data configured to test a program unit by running it under varying conditions and monitoring its behavior and outputs. It has two main parts: the test execution engine and the test script repository.

Here's discussion ([Comparison of c++ unit test frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242926/comparison-of-c-unit-test-frameworks)) about c++ unit test frameworks.