# Which unit test framework to use for c++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, cmake

Which unit test framework is in your opinion the best? It should be possible to use with c++/cmake projects. 
If possible it should have a eclipse plugin for it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/242926/1741542. If you need more, try http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%2B%2B]+unit+test+is%3Aq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of unit test frameworks for C++. But I like [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) most. Its design is modern, and [supports awesome features](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md). It is a header-only library, so easy to use.

Comment: [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest) is my reimplementation of Catch with a huge focus on compilation speed - checkout the [FAQ](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/faq.md#how-is-doctest-different-from-catch) to see whats different

Comment: @onqtam: Cool reimplementation. Thanks for sharing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the boost unit testing [framework](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/test/doc/components/utf/index.html). Here's a link to a tutorial on how to use it. It's fairly straight fforward: [tutorials](https://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2009/07/04/c-unit-tests-with-boost-test-part-1/)