# Unit Testing Native C++ In Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

I've been using Visual Studio Code to develop a low-level C++ library on a Mac. It seems to integrate with the compiler toolchain quite gracefully. But as to Unit Testing, I'm totally lost. There are a [myriad of frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242926/comparison-of-c-unit-test-frameworks) out there, none of them having been established as a standard, the way JUnit has. Moreover, the Visual Studio Code Unit Test Explorer has been very [scantily documented](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-dotnet-test-explorer).

Which unit testing frameworks integrate well with the Code frontend? How should one set up a unit testing project? I'm using SCons but I can switch to another build system if necessary.

Comment: If you are using CMake then Boost.Tests works great with CMake. I'm always setting up tests to build and auto run when building debug build.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know what works well with SCons? Also, do you get to use the Code frontend to run and monitor your tests?

Comment: Unfortunately I have never used SCons. I'm not sure about Code frontend, I just prefer console for such tasks, but I'm almost certain that it is possible to setup Code to build by pressing F5 or whatever and built-in console pops up with compilation and then tests output.

Answer (score 3):

For CMake. This is minimal setup for Code.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O2")

add_library(example ./some-path/example.cpp)

project(tests)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.55 REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ./tests/tests.cpp)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} example ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cd build && make" // cd to your build directory
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I can `SHIFT` + `CTRL` + `b` to build my project and CMake will show me Boost.Tests (passed/failed) at the end of compiling output in built-in Code console.

Example output of Code's console:

```
> Executing task: cd build && make <

[ 75%] Built target example
Scanning dependencies of target tests
[ 87%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tests.dir/tests/tests.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable tests
Running 74 test cases...

*** No errors detected
[100%] Built target tests

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```